# Update Blob data using Azure function

Tags: c#, azure, function

I have an excel file in container in Azure storage account. I need to update the rows of a column with an input parameter dynamically using an Azure function using C# preferably using an BlobTrigger template. Already have the code to read the blob but did not find anything to update the file.

Thanks

I tried using the SpreadsheetDocument class but could not go far.

Comment: please share the code which you have tried?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with blob storage. Blobs are not files. They are just binary data. If you want to modify the file whose data is stored in that blob then you need to download the data and either save it as a file or create some appropriate object from the data and modify that, then save back to blob storage. The modifying part is independent. You need to do a bit more work before you have a question appropriate for asking here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download the blob alter it locally and then push it back up if you want to to do this, this would cause issues if file is being accessed by multiple users at the same time.

You should look into an SQL database storage solutions.

I have provided you with simple upload/download blob methods should you want to experiment. You will need to insert your own logic updating the document locally.

```
public async Task DownloadBlob()
{
    var blob = "<BLOB_NAME>";

    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse( "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<ACCOUNT_NAME>;AccountKey=<ACCOUNT_KEY>");
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("<CONTAINER_NAME>");
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blob);

    string path = $@"C:\Temp\{blob}.csv";
    string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

    if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
    }

    try
    {
        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(path))
        {
            await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(fileStream);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}

public async Task UploadBlob()
{
    string path = @"C:\Temp\<BLOB_NAME>.csv";

    try
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse( "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<ACCOUNT_NAME>;AccountKey=<ACCOUNT_KEY>");
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("<CONTAINER_NAME>");
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobFilePath.Split(@"\Temp\").LastOrDefault());

        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobFilePath.Split(@"\Temp\").Last());

        await blob.UploadFromFileAsync(blobFilePath);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```